# Seeking better understanding of Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm quite confused on the one part of the Fourier transform. I don't understand what is the term $\left(u*x + v*y \right)$ mean. I mean $u$ and $v$ are the axis for frequency domain and $x$, $y$ are the axis for time domain, but why do we multiply them, I see how they derive it, but what is the actual meaning of it? I don't quite the meaning from the derivation. If possible could you explain?

Comment: Hi, please read the chatjax tutorial

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, what is chatjax?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will read it.